# How to read git commits from hard disk in my software?

Tags: c#, git

I want to make a time tracking utility in C# to make a rough estimate of per-developer time poured into a versioned project, so far this is my strategy:

1. iterate all commits in master
2. identify commit clusters within X minutes of each other
3. get time delta between frst and last commit in each cluster and compute "code speed" using change size
4. based on average "code speed" times change size I estimate the amount of time spent doing isolated commits
5. everything is summed and listed

This is not a full solution but one idea I wanted to develop to get an initial estimate of spent time given a pre-existing repository and seed a proper time tracking tool with it.

The core of the question is how can I interface my program with the git repository in order to get the commit data for the current/master branch? Is spawning a shell and piping the result to c# the only possibility? aka how do i get the info by reading the filesystem myself ?

Comment: _"make a rough estimate of per-developer time poured into a versioned project"_ - it is highly improbable that you can infer actual effort a developer has spent developing something just by looking at commit time.  I doubt you will succeed

Comment: i know this is not the most optimal way, but we didn't start with time tracking until now, so we need some numbers to discuss afterward. just as a suggestion.

Comment: Also, "per-developer time poured into" vs. "code speed" might be completely different. A good programmer might spend a whole day figuring out how to change one line, whereas a poor programmer will spend the whole day adding thousands of additional code lines, to fix the exact same issue. So as for "discuss afterwards", be prepared for a lively discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading filesystem would require understanding how git structures its database in the files. That is overkill IMO for the task you want to do. I'd suggest some library like [libgit2sharp](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp) that exposes git methods which you can use to perform your iterations.